# How many ternary (0, 1, 2) sequences of length 10 are there without any pair of consecutive digits the same?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ternary (0, 1, 2) sequences of length 10 are there without any pair of
consecutive digits the same?

Not sure if I understood the question correctly. 
It's asking for possible 10 digit number with $0, 1, 2$ and no consecutive digits.

My thoughts are if there are 10 spaces then the first space will be $3\choose 1$, second one cannot be the same with the first one so it will have to be $2\choose 1$.

So it will come down to  $3\times 2^9$. Can someone correct if I'm wrong ?

Comment: There is no correction necessary - you have done this correctly

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: I would simply add one thing: "$\ldots$ second one cannot be the same with the first one so it will have to be $2 \choose 1$, *and the same holds for the remaining eight*."

Answer (score 1):

This is correct...................

Comment: LOL at your clever use of periods................................................................................

Comment: @heropup: it had been edited incorrectly and I wrote an answer pointing out the problem.  Then I noticed that there was an edit and that OP had it right, but there was no answer.  I needed some more characters to meet the minimum of 30